# Where is the Sqlite file in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova

I used PhoneGap to create a Sqlite db and access it to read data. So I want to find out where the Sqlite file is located in my android device. Please show me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use phonegap then your database will be at location

```
/data/data/package-name/app_database/file__0/0000000000000001.db
```

And all your tables will be stored there....

Comment: thanks, I used adb tool to check this.but is there any way else to see the file??

Comment: Yup Many ways... u can go for this http://www.tylerfrankenstein.com/browse-android-emulator-sqlite-database-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

If your package is `com.exampl.hello` then

```
/data/data/com.example.hello/databases/databasefile
```

where `databasefile` is the name of your database.

Comment: data folder in my device is empty, I couldn't find the location you mention

Comment: How can I download this file from adb shell...?

Comment: Take a look at `adb pull` : http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html

Comment: @enrmarc Phonegap will not store the database in the location u mentioned... The location u mentioned is Android's Default database location.....